# predict sequence of tuples using Transformer model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, transformer-model, seq2seq

I am fairly new to seq2seq models and transformers.

Basically I am working on a sequence generation problem. I want to use the transformer. I am using python and pyTorch.

I know how the transformer model works for a sequence generation like given `[1,2,3]` it can generate `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
But the problem I am facing is that, in my dataset each point/element in the sequence has 2 attributes. So, the sequence looks like following:

```
[(2,4), (1,8), (1,9)]
```

and the generated sequence will be:

```
[(2,4), (1,8), (1,9), (3,1), (2,9)]
```

The first element of each tuple can be between 1-5 and the second element can be between 1-10.

I want to follow the general approach of Transformers like creating embedding for each element, pass it through a decoder block of multihead attention and pointwise feed forward network and finally use softmax to sample out the output.

My question is, as each data point contains 2 values, how do I change the transformer model to work with this kind of sequences? Any direction will be appreciated. Thanks.